# Type not found in xmlns build error when using third party control library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a third party control in my Xamarin forms project through nuget. I added a xmlns to my xaml for the library, but when I build I get the error: `Type flv:FlowListView not found in xmlns clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.Helpers.FlowListView;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView`

Using the following xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.Helpers.FlowListView;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
             x:Class="FScruiser.XF.Pages.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <flv:FlowListView>
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="text"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls
```

instead of

```
clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.Helpers.FlowListView
```

So, the full namespace definition is this:

```
xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
```

**Edit:** You can also see it in action [here on GitHub](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/blob/master/Samples/DLToolkitControlsSamples/SamplesFlowListView/SimplePage.xaml#L3), in one of the samples.

Comment: thanks. I made the mistake typing FlowListView and just selected the first namespace that came up in intellisense.

Comment: @bit2know You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it works now.